# How to make div document selected without clicking on it using jquery ? (Auto suggest with Scrolbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, onkeydown

I am working facing issue in auto suggest with scroll bar. I have to make scroll bar movable on arrow key down, mouse wheel its works fine for me. If I use document keydown event its moving my browser scroll.

I just looking for a functionality with arrow keydown scroll should move. If I click inside the div and try to move scroll bar with arrow keydown its works but if I am not clicking inside div, since document is not clicked scroll bar doesn't work.

I used slimscroll and currently working with enscroll-0.4 plugins but not able to make it fixed. Feel free to ask if you are not clear about my question.

It will be really helpful if anyone have a solution for this issue.

Comment: can you show us some code, maybe a fiddle we can modify? also, did you try focusing on the control (by using .focus() or something) so it changes the focus from document to the control.

Comment: can yo handle the `.animate()` of the `div`, use the `scrollTop` property of the element

Comment: Yes I have used focus() but not getting solution which I expect. Please have a look at the plugin demo which i used - http://enscrollplugin.com/#demos Scroll bar moves by pressing arrow key down only when we select any content inside the div.